# Invalidate picturescrollfield

Tags: blackberry

I am loading images in `PictureScrollField` from the server and want that until images are loaded from server, the `PictureScrollField` shows a blank image and when the image loads in image array, it repaints (redraw) the `PictureScrollField` like a `ListField`.

I read from BlackBerry documentation that every field can be invalidated (that is, we can repaint it) but when I use the `PictureScrollField.invalidate()` method in my program, I get an error :

> The method invalidate from the type Field is not visible

The program I use is listed below

```java
public final class GetMoreImage extends MainScreen {
    public static PictureScrollField psf;
    int size;
    int length;
    String text=null;
    EncodedImage[] encodedImage;
    VerticalFieldManager vmanger;
    private LoadImages loadImages;

    public GetMoreImage(int index) {
        super(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
        this.size=index;
        try {
            length=ListHome.object[size].getJSONArray("UrlArray").length();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ScrollEntry[] entries = new ScrollEntry[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(encodedImage != null && encodedImage.length > i && encodedImage[i] != null) {
                EncodedImage encodedImg =ListHome.sizeImage(JPEGEncodedImage.encode(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png"),80),640,380);
                Bitmap bmp=encodedImg.getBitmap();
                entries[i] = new ScrollEntry(bmp, "hello", "");
            }
            else {
                try {
                    text=ListHome.object[size].getJSONArray("UrlArray").getString(i).toString();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                EncodedImage encodedImg =ListHome.sizeImage(JPEGEncodedImage.encode(connectServerForImage(text),80),640,380);
                Bitmap bmp=encodedImg.getBitmap();
                entries[i] = new ScrollEntry(bmp, "hello", "");
            }
        }

        psf = new PictureScrollField();
        psf.setData(entries, 0);
        psf.setHighlightStyle(HighlightStyle.ILLUMINATE_WITH_SHRINK_LENS);
        add(psf);
        loadImages = new LoadImages(80, 80);
        loadImages.start();
    }

    private class LoadImages extends Thread {
        int widthL;
        int heightL;

        LoadImages(int width, int height) {
            this.widthL = width;
            this.heightL = height;
        }

        public void run() {
            encodedImage=new EncodedImage[length];
            if (ListHome.object[size] != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    try {
                        String text=ListHome.object[size].getJSONArray("UrlArray").getString(i).toString();
                        EncodedImage encodedImg = JPEGEncodedImage.encode(connectServerForImage(text), 80);//Get Image from Server
                        encodedImage[i] = ListHome.sizeImage(encodedImg, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight()-100);
                        psf.invalidate();//This Line generate error
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Dialog.alert("No Data Found");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get a **compile** error on this line:

```java
 psf.invalidate();//This Line generate error
```

is because the `PictureScrollField#invalidate()` [method is protected, not public.](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#invalidate%28%29)  So, code not in `PictureScrollField` or a class that extends `PictureScrollField` cannot use it directly.

However, you don't **need** to use `invalidate()`.  `invalidate()` is a low-level method that instructs a field to repaint.  However, `PictureScrollField` has a higher-level method that is designed to allow you to change images, and have the field (re)draw them:  `PictureScrollField#setData()`.

Because that method is changing the user interface (UI), it should be run on the UI/main thread.  This will not automatically happen if you make the call inside the `run()` method you are using to download the images.  So, you'll need something like this inside your `LoadImages` class:

```java
public void run() {
    encodedImage=new EncodedImage[length];
    if (ListHome.object[size] != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {              
            try {
                String text=ListHome.object[size].getJSONArray("UrlArray").getString(i).toString();
                EncodedImage encodedImg = JPEGEncodedImage.encode(connectServerForImage(text), 80);//Get Image from Server                          
                encodedImage[i] = ListHome.sizeImage(encodedImg, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight()-100);

                //psf.invalidate();//This Line generate error
                entries[i] = new ScrollEntry(encodedImage[i].getBitmap(), "label", "callout");
                // we must update the scroll entries on the UI/main thread:
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                   // setting the field to index 'i' will scroll to the image
                   //   that was just downloaded
                   psf.setData(entries, i);
                });                        
            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

In order to make this work, you must change the local `entries` variable to a **member variable** in your `GetMoreImage` class:

```java
 public final class GetMoreImage extends MainScreen {
     public static PictureScrollField psf;
     private ScrollEntry[] entries;
```

but, you can still *instantiate* it (`entries = new ScrollEntry[length];`) in your screen's constructor, or whenever you know the correct length.

Comment: Really you are a genius person .Today I implemented what I want.I appreciate for this.Further It is an request to you to Please See this link and suggest what to do next  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636394/facebook-login-in-blackberry-6

Comment: :Still waiting for your respons for this Question :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636394/facebook-login-in-blackberry-6e for Question